# How do I join all cells except current cell in google docs?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I want to join all cells in the current column, except the current one (to avoid circular dependency) in google docs.

I'm looking for something like:

```
JOIN(",";FILTER(A:A;IF_NOT_CURRENT_CELL))
```

Or maybe even like this (just ignore all errors):

```
JOIN(",";FILTER(A:A;IFERROR(??,FALSE))
```

Asssuming the formular I'm looking for is written in line 4, the output should look like this:

[image: example output]

Comment: obv. a simple `=JOIN(",";A:A)` doesn't work because of circular dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly, but that seems to be a layout issue:

```
 =textjoin(",";1;{transpose(Indirect("A1:A"&Row()-1))\transpose(indirect("A"&row()+1&":A"))})
```